# If $G \cong H$, $N \trianglelefteq G$, $K \trianglelefteq H$, $N \cong K$, do we have $G/N \cong H/K$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G \cong H$ be 2 isomorphic groups, $N \trianglelefteq G$ and $K \trianglelefteq H$ be normal subgroups such that $N \cong K$. If we consider their quotient groups, do we have $G/N \cong H/K$ ? I think this is true if we can find an isomorphism $\phi : G \mapsto H$ such that the restriction $\phi_{\restriction N}$ is an isomorphism between $N$ and $K$. But does such a $\phi$ always exist ? Or is it not even necessary to find such a $\phi$ ?

I wanted to see if we could prove $A \times B \cong A \times C \Rightarrow B \cong C$, where $A, B, C$ are finite abelian groups, without the decomposition into cyclic groups. I wondered if we could consider the quotients $(A \times B)/(A \times \{0_B\})$ and $(A \times C)/(A \times \{0_C\})$ and say they are isomorphic by applying such a result.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not even true with $G = H$. For instance, take $G = H = \mathbb{Z}$ and $N = 2\mathbb{Z}, K = 3\mathbb{Z}$. Your condition may help things, however.

Comment: Hint: look at $C_2\times C_4$ ($C_n$ is a cyclic group o f size $n$).

Comment: @AlexWertheim you beat me in time I think.

Comment: @Gianluca: great minds think alike. :)

Comment: I think this is true! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is false. Consider $G=H=\Bbb Z$ and $N=\langle 2\rangle$, $K =\langle 3\rangle$. We have that $K\cong N$, but $G/N \cong \Bbb Z_2$ and $H/K \cong \Bbb Z_3$.